# Is there an XLib alternative for glXSwapBuffers()?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, xlib

I want my application to instantly draw all the data to a display. In windows there is `SwapBuffers()` function to do such kind of things, where you can do all the drawings to a second virtual window and then swap that virtual window with an existing one. OpenGL provides a `glXSwapBuffers()` function to do roughly the same. However I don't want to use it. Therefore, I am curios, what are the ways to implement this functionality in pure XLib

Comment: The function `SwapBuffers` on windows calls internally is `wglSwapBuffers` of the OpenGL ICD DLL. OpenGL does not provide `glxSwapBuffers`, nor `wglSwapBuffers`, that functions are part of the platform's GL binding APIs, and these can't be replaced by anything else if you still directly want to render to onscreen buffers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In X11 there are the `Pixmap` resources which are considered as `Drawable` (like `Window`).

Then you can draw to a `Pixmap` using as many steps as necessary, and finally use `XCopyArea()` to send the resulting drawing to a `Window`.

Note that a `Pixmap` stands on the server side, like a `Window`, so the final copy operation is local to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is the X Double Buffer Extension: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libXext/dbelib.html

> The Double Buffer Extension (DBE) provides a standard way to utilize
> double-buffering within the framework of the X Window System.

Protocol: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/dbe.html

Never seen it used in practice. Let me know if you pull it off.